# Windows Phone - Uploading Files to OneDrive Application Registration

Tags: windows-phone, onedrive

I am able to upload files to OneDrive using the API

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/SkyDrive_-_How_to_upload_content_on_Windows_Phone

I would like to register my Windows Phone App but the application management site does not seem to work

https://manage.dev.live.com/

Is there there any other way I can register my app for OneDrive?

Comment: Both links don't work any more :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

First of all go to [One Drive Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/onedrive) and do login then go do `Dashboard`, You would be redirected to Register app Wizard that is [Register Application](https://account.live.com/developers/applications/create)

Comment: I did check this link it says "If you want to register an application for Windows 8.1 or Windows Phone 8.1, go to the Windows Store Dashboard instead." - But i am not able to see the registration on Windows Store Dashboard

Comment: be clear what r u looking for ? for windows phone or windows and for 8 or 8.1

Comment: I am trying to register one drive for Windows Phone

Comment: but for 8 or 8.1 ? for 8.1 we can have App Registration in store although this above link would work for phone 8 and also for 8.1. You can try above thing.